# Cant add a object to my list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**I have a model like this:**

```
public class Balance
{
    public int BalanceId { get; set; }
    public List<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
    public List<Income> Incomes { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
}
```

this model has 2 list of 2 models Expense and Income.

So what i want is to add a Expense to my List of Expenses and im trying to do that in my Controller here:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ExpenseId,TipoDespesaId,DespesaDescricao,DespesaValor,TipoPagamentoId,Data,Comentario")] Expense expense)
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var balance = db.Balance.Where(d => d.ApplicationUserId == userId).FirstOrDefault();


            expense.ApplicationUserId = userId;

            if (balance == null)
            {
                Balance b = new Balance();
                s.Expense.Add(expense);
                s.ApplicationUserId = userId;               
            }
            else
            {
                balance.expense.Add(despesa);
            }

            db.Despesas.Add(expense);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.TipoDespesaId = new SelectList(db.TipoDespesas.Where(m => m.ApplicationUserId == userId), "TipoDespesaId", "TipoDespesaNome", despesa.TipoDespesaId);
        ViewBag.TipoPagamentoId = new SelectList(db.TipoPagamentos.Where(m => m.ApplicationUserId == userId), "TipoPagamentoId", "TipoPagamentoNome", despesa.TipoPagamentoId);
        return View(despesa);
    }
```

**The Error is here:**

```
 if (balance == null)
    {
      Balance b = new Balance();
      s.Expense.Add(expense);
      s.ApplicationUserId = userId;               
    }
```

It says this **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"**
if someone can help me to understand what i am doing wrong i aprecciate

Ps: Sorry for my bad english but i want to learn more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize your list properties. An easy way to do this is in the constructor of your entity:

```
public class Balance
{
    public Balance()
    {
        Expenses = new List<Expense>();
        Incomes = new List<Income>();
    }

    public int BalanceId { get; set; }
    public List<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
    public List<Income> Incomes { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, can you explain me why it dont work without initializing so i understand what i am doing, cause if i already have a list on my model Balance why i need to initialize it?? sorry for Newbie questions

Comment: `Expenses` is null until you initialize it. Creating an instance of `Balance` doesn't initialize its properties, unless initialize them in the constructor as shown above.